# Динамическое создание элемента

Tags: asp.net

Здравствуйте! На странице есть поле ввода, кнопка и label (метка). Пользователь вводит текст, нажимает на кнопку. Появляется введенный текст в метке и динамически добавляется кнопка 'Clear'. При нажатии на кнопку 'Clear', текст в поле ввода и текст в метке должен удалиться. Но этого не происходит. Подскажите, что я сделал не так? Вот два файла.
**Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div id="a" runat="server">
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   &nbsp;&nbsp;
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
   <br />
   <br />
   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
   <br />
   <br />
  </div>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page {
 //создание новой кнопки
 Button button2 = new Button();
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

 }
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text;

  //id для новой кнопки
  button2.ID = "Button2";
  //текст новой кнопки
  button2.Text = "Clear";
  //добавляем новую кнопку
  a.Controls.Add(button2);
  //обработчик события
  button2.Click += button2_Click;
 }

 void button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
  //очищает поле ввода
  TextBox1.Text = null;
  //очищает вывод
  Label1.Text = null;
 }
}
```

**По видимому, никто не может решить такую задачку...**

**А быть может, так...**

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page {
 //создание новой кнопки
 Button button2 = new Button();
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  //id для новой кнопки
  button2.ID = "Button2";
  //текст новой кнопки
  button2.Text = "Clear";
  //добавляем новую кнопку
  a.Controls.Add(button2);
  //обработчик события
  button2.Click += button2_Click;
  //button2.Click += new EventHandler(button2_Click);
  //делаем кнопку невидимой
  button2.Visible = false;
 }

 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text;
  //делаем кнопку видимой
  button2.Visible = true;
 }

 void button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
  //очищает поле ввода
  TextBox1.Text = null;
  //очищает вывод
  Label1.Text = null;
 }
}
```

Comment: А может быть, кто-то и сможет...

Comment: Вы просто делаете это слишком поздно - нужно делать НЕ позже пейдж-лоада.

Comment: Если поместить создание кнопки в Page_Load, то кнопка будет создаваться при загрузке страницы, но при этом будет очищать поле ввода и вывод. Но тогда вся задумка будет не выполнена. Ее исправить можно с помощью атрибута Visibly. В Page_Load сделать ее false, а в Button1_Click сделать ее true. Или я ошибаюсь?